# Docker compose project name hides underscore in bash but not in gitlab-CI

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a docker-compose file for our infrastructure which works perfectly.

By default when I enter it in a folder /prod it will name the stack "prod", which I can see e.g. in portainer.

Now, I want the name to be with a underscore, like "infra_prod" and "infra_test".

When I do this in gitlab CI file like:

```
script:
   - docker-compose -p "intra_test" up
```

It works fine.

When I log into the server by SSH with my windows powershell and enter it then in the bash:

```
docker-compose -p "intra_test" up
```

It works but the name is infratest instead of infra_test.

Same rule applies for dots.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project name input has underscores removed by docker-compose as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2119).

There are plans to change this behaviour as tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/745).